# Как отдать файл на скачивание в фреймворке yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть такой пост запрос

```
 $.ajax({
            type   : 'POST',
            cache  : false,
            url    : '*****',
            data   :  'fghfghfgh',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === 'ok')
                {
                  console.log('~~~~~~~1~~~',data)
                }
                else
                {
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('href',data);
                    link.setAttribute('download','download');
                    link.click();
                    // console.log('~~~~2~~~~~~',data)
                }
            }
        });
```

Я принимаю запрос и получаю файл. 
Мне надо отдать браузеру этот файл для того, что бы клиент его скачал себе.
В интернете посмотрел все варианты какие нашёл, файл не начинает скачиваться, а ответом приходит в  ajax запрос отсюда.

```
  public function actionDownload()
        {
            \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            $model = new Converter();
            if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
           .....
            }
            $file = Yii::getAlias('@backend/uploads/uploadslocal_9i5xxzsgrujvedvtbo.jpg');
            return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);

        }
```

Как мне сделать что бы файл не отправлялся ответом обратно, а начинал скачиваться ?

Comment: У меня была похожая задача, мне нужно было при клике на кнопку Сохранить картинку, обратиться к php, отрисовать её и отправить обратно браузеру где пользователь при клике на кнопку получал окно на сохранение файла из браузера, вам такое нужно?

Comment: похоже в целом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action для загрузки. Код по свои нужды можете поправить.

```
    /**
     * @param $filename string      Название файла
     * @param $expansion string     Расширение файла
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionDownload($filename, $expansion) {
        $filePath = '../uploads/' . $filename . '.' . $expansion;

        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $mime  = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);
            finfo_close($finfo);
            $size  = filesize($filePath);

            header("Content-Type: ".$mime);
            header("Content-Length: ".$size);
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . '.' . $expansion . "\"");
            readfile($filePath);
        } else {
            throw new CHttpException(404, 'Файл не найден');
        }

        exit;
    }
```

На стороне js есть смысла при успешном запросе делать редирект на ссылку загрузки или использовать, например, [jQuery File Download](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/).

Answer (score 1):

Если это вам поможет, в методе контроллера (в моем случае это фреймворк CodeIgniter) мы задаем заголовок документа через php, в котором и говорим что ответом выполнения скрипта является бинарный файл, после наполняем его данными (здесь я подгружаю картинку и наношу на неё текст) и браузер видя эти данные распознает я так понял их как совместимый файл где и предлагает сохранить его на ПК.

[image: Подгружаем фон, рисуем на нем код и отдаем на сохранение в браузер пользователю]

Comment: Я отдельными сервисами сделал преобразование doc документа в картинку и потом наложение произвольного текста, на созранённый пресет из базы данных.

Мне надо метод на подобиии того, что есть в js. Посмотрю у вас код может быть поможет.

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href','http://javascript.ru/forum/images/ca_serenity/misc/logo.gif');
link.setAttribute('download','download');
onload=link.click();